# Bootstrap -datetimepicker.js for french language

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

when i changed the locale from browser from english to french then every thing is displaying in French except calender .My code is below-  please help me out how to dispaly the calender in french.

Comment: There is no code ;-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say which plugin you are using. The principle is the same for these two :

1. [**First plugin**](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) :

   ```
   $('#your_calendar').datetimepicker({
       locale: 'fr'
       // Others functions
   });
   ```

According to the [documentation](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#locale), you must include `moment-with-locales.js` or a local js file.

> See [momentjs](https://github.com/moment/moment/tree/develop/locale) for valid locales.

---

2. [**Second plugin**](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) :

   ```
   $('#your_calendar').datetimepicker({
       lang: 'fr',
       // Others functions
   });
   ```